# Why does function not get executed when called through web server?

Tags: python, ajax, apache2, raspberry-pi, raspbian

There is a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call("sudo /var/www/scripts/setPwm "+ sys.argv[1],shell=True)
print ("Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n\n")
print("sudo /var/www/scripts/setPwm "+ sys.argv[1])
print("ok\n")
```

When run locally it lights up a LED with specified intensity. When called through a website it prints all correctly, but the LED does not light up.

When I call

```
http://sauna/scripts/setLED.py?1000
```

this is printed:

```
sudo /var/www/scripts/setPwm 1000
ok
```

so the argument is apparently passed correctly, there are also no errors in apache log. Still there is no light :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that apache servers runs as a different user (`www-data`) than I. Adding the user (`www-data`) to `/etc/sudoers` for the particular executable that needs to be run as root helped.